# How to programmatically add data from sql to a listview in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, listview

I am trying to populate a listview on my page. I use code to read data from sql:

```
string cxnstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cxnstr);
        ds = new DataSet("ds");
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select d.[Title],d.[Link],d.[Description],s.[Title],s.[Link],s.[Description] from DomainLinks d,SupplierLinks s where s.SuppRowID = " + SuppRowID + " or d.SuppRowID = " + SuppRowID, conn);
            da.Fill(ds);


        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                lstView.DataSource = ds;

                lstView.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {

                lblError.Text = "There are no links for that type";
            }
        }
```

which goes into listview:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
            <br />
        <a href='<%#Eval("Link") %>' runat="server"><asp:Label ID="LinkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Link") %>' /></a>
            <br />
        <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
            <br />
</asp:ListView>
```

which works fine. but my problem is what about the other records?
I have no idea how to add more records to the listview short of adding:

```
<asp:Label ID="Title1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title1") %>' />
            <br />
        <a href='<%#Eval("Link1") %>' runat="server"><asp:Label ID="Link1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Link1") %>' /></a>
            <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Description1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description1") %>' />
            <br />
```

and incrementing. But that is hard coded. How do I do this on a page load? Should I continue using a listview? Switch controls?

EDIT

ok. this is the table structure for both domain links and supply links:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SupplierLinks](
[RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SuppRowID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Title] [varchar](250) NULL,
[Link] [varchar](max) NULL,
[Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RowID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DomainLinks](
[RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SuppRowID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Title] [varchar](250) NULL,
[Link] [varchar](max) NULL,
[Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RowID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

the parent table is just a title and the rowid they inherit from as a foreign key.
in my code, a user selects a supplier from a dropdownlist, I get the id and that is in the select statement.

sometimes, most times, the results would be more than one.

hope this clarifies the situation

Comment: the code written above will only display values that are already present in your SQL Database Table. to add new records, you need to write a different logic.

Comment: Are you talking about s.xxx vs d.xxx in your select statement?  If so, why wouldn't you just change them from being the same column name by adding `As 'Domain Title'`, `As 'Supplier Title'`, etc.?

Comment: @PraveenNambiar that is fine. I only want the records in the database. no new records that I create in code.

Comment: @Scott its fine because they are essentially the same. it will still have a title, link and description. just want to see all the records

Comment: You should be able to see them all. Are you saying you only see 1 row? You can check out all the examples on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4) if you want.

Comment: @Scott that's right. I only see one record, unless I add more item templates as my example above.

Comment: @NicholasAysen you need to check your query again. you have put a where clause which mentions the ID. i believe the query returns just one record.

Comment: ^^^ That's what I'm thinking too

Comment: What's the structure of you database?  I think Praveen and Scott are on the right track as well.

Comment: sorry it took so long for editing, but pls see above add-ins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is fine now.
I made a new page, that finds the foreign keys for the data that I want and the title.
based on these two variables, I can draw the single row out of sql.

```
protected void hypTit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is LinkButton)
        {
            lstArt.Visible = true;
            LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
            string buttonpressed = btn.Text.ToString();
            fillVals(buttonpressed);
        }
    }

    protected void fillVals(String name)
    {
        string cxnstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cxnstr);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds;
        try
        {
            ds = new DataSet("ds");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Title,[Description]as[Article] from StandardReplies where CatRowID = " + catID + " and Title like '" + name + "'", conn);
            da.Fill(ds);
            lstArt.DataSource = ds;
            lstArt.DataBind();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

something like that. don't want to give too much away